# Dificuldade com Encoding

Tags: html, banco-de-dados, codificação-de-caracteres

Boas,

Eu tenho um ficheiro *PHP* com *encoding* UTF-8. E o texto com acentos na parte *HTML* ficam como deve ser mas quando vou buscar à base de dados aparecem caracteres esquisitos.

[Encoding da base de dados](http://gyazo.com/651d707f1ef3bf4002603660577a6f39)

[Dados da base de dados](http://gyazo.com/f8f930accdc5876cb6912724c87d5247)

[Dados da base de dados vistos no ficheiro *php*](http://gyazo.com/3461ed8fd5e9e9edaaf51a727b705ed4)

```html
include("connection.php");
<?php
   include("connection.php");

   echo "<div class='narrow-block wrapper'>
<h2>Inscrições (Federados)</h2>
<table id='table2'>
    $result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM registofederados");
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
  echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['dorsal'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['nome'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['bi'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['dataNasc'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['n_federado'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['telemovel'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['morada'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['local_dorsal'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['pagamento'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['equipa'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['categoria'] . "km </td>";
   if($row['almoco'] == 1)
    echo "<td>Sim</td>";
   else
    echo "<td>Não</td>";
   if($row['pago'] == 1)
    echo "<td>Sim</td>";
   else
    echo "<td>Não</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
 }
    </table>
  </div>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Caso você use o **notepad++** e para evitar futuros problemas vá no menu de opções, clica em `Format`, e seleciona a codificação `UTF-8(Sem BOM)`, você pode definir isso por padrão nas configurações, para assim que criar um arquivo ele já venha em `UTF-8(Sem BOM)`, caso já tenha um código escrito em `ANSI` você deve clicar em **Converter para UTF-8(Sem BOM)** ele converte não sendo necessário correções nos acentos por exemplo, pois já faz isso automaticamente. Lembre-se **UTF-8(Sem BOM)** sem `BOM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executa o seguinte comando antes de executares a query:

```
if( function_exists('mysql_set_charset') ) { 
    mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con); 
} else { 
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $con); 
}
```

Podes também mudar o encoding da tua base de dados para:

```
utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: eu tenho isso mas o problema é nos dados que vêm da base de dados, que os acentos vêm em caracteres esquisitos como referido e mostrado em cima

Comment: Penso que já percebi o seu problema, tente executar o seguinte comando antes da execução da query: mysql_set_charset("utf8");

Comment: Tipo assim:      mysql_set_charset("utf8");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM registo where tipo = 0");

Comment: Tipo assim: $conn = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $conn);

Comment: Eu sou um pouco novo nisto de base de dados com php. E agora está a dar-me o seguinte erro: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\exercicios\OxygenTarget\php\verregistosA.php on line 211 e o código em que dá erro é : $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM registo where tipo='0'"); O que é isso?

Comment: Podes por favor mostrar como é que estás a fazer? Coloca no post principal o teu código PHP para de ajudar melhor.

Comment: Pronto @Hélder já está ai um pouco do código acho que é isso o relevante

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24996/discussion-between-helder-and-bruno-gibellino).